# An event in adapter keep firing non stop

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I have set `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for `Checkbox` in my View, this View represent a row in `listView`, When I check this Checkbox, the `onCheckedChanged()` function keep running non-stop! how to make it run just once per check?
this code is in the adapter of the `listView`:

```
checkedItem.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d("--esmaSel--", "check result="+isChecked);
            if(isChecked) {
               if (!callRecorderClass.CheckedItemsIDs.contains(allCalls.get(position).getStringExtra(DBmanager.ID)))
                   callRecorderClass.CheckedItemsIDs.add(allCalls.get(position).getStringExtra(DBmanager.ID));
           }    else {
                Log.d("--esmaSel--", "remove---");
               callRecorderClass.CheckedItemsIDs.remove(allCalls.get(position).getStringExtra(DBmanager.ID));
           }
            //todo:Send a BroadCast that change is made

            Intent topMenuNoty=new Intent();
            Log.d("--esmaSel--", "will send BC"+position);
            topMenuNoty.setAction("showHide");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).
            sendBroadcast(topMenuNoty);

        }
    });
```

it sends many broadcasts when I just check it once! and I check the position it is the same position! may this help? 
**HERE IS MY RECEIVER**

```
public BroadcastReceiver refresh = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Extract data included in the Intent
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d("--sel--", "got ShowHide");
        if (action.equals("showHide"))
            {
                Log.d("--sel--", "got " + action);
                View v= findViewById(R.id.top_menu);
                Log.d("--sel--", "null view ");

                if(v==null) return;
                if(CheckedItemsIDs.isEmpty())
                  findViewById(R.id.top_menu).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                else findViewById(R.id.top_menu).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                List<Intent> list= new DBmanager(context).getInboxCalls();
                if(list!=null&&list.size()>0) {
                    ListView inboxCalls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.indexCalls);
                    inboxCalls.setAdapter(new inboxAdapter(context,R.layout.incox_call_row,list));


                }
            }



    }
};
```

Comment: use flag concept. if u want  only once to be executed

Comment: Can you post your broadcastReceiver?

Comment: see the edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ok** I see that setAdapter in the receiver must be removed, I just remove these lines and everything is ok now:

```
                List<Intent> list= new DBmanager(context).getInboxCalls();
            if(list!=null&&list.size()>0) {
                ListView inboxCalls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.indexCalls);
                inboxCalls.setAdapter(new inboxAdapter(context,R.layout.incox_call_row,list));
```